# Error in eval(expr; p): PDF parsing failure

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, eval

I don´t understand the error itself and what I need to change in the code.
Even if I only run the first part (minutes), the error "Error in eval(expr; p): PDF parsing failure" comes up.

```
read_poland_minute_links<-function(){
  part<-xml2::read_html("https://nbp.pl/en/monetary-policy/mpc-documents/mpc-minutes/")%>%
    rvest::html_nodes("a")%>%
    rvest::html_attr("href")
  
  part<-part[grepl("mi_|voting",part)]
  
  return(part)
}

read_poland_ir_links<-function(){
  part<-xml2::read_html("https://nbp.pl/en/monetary-policy/mpc-documents/inflation-report/")%>%
    rvest::html_nodes("a")%>%
    rvest::html_attr("href")
  
  part<-part[grepl(".pdf",part)]
  
  return(part)
}

read_poland_release_links<-function(){
  part<-xml2::read_html("https://nbp.pl/en/monetary-policy/mpc-documents/monetary-policy-council-press-releases/")%>%
    rvest::html_nodes("a")%>%
    rvest::html_attr("href")
  
  part<-part[grepl(".pdf",part)]
  
  return(part)
}
```

I tried to scrape the minutes from Poland and expected that it would work.

Comment: You are getting an error when you run `read_poland_minute_links()`? I cannot replicate. It runs for me and returns a list of URLs. Maybe include the output of `sessionInfo()` so we can see all the packages you have loaded. Maybe there's a conflict with a function name. You can also test for that with `conflicts(detail=TRUE)`